# server and client in java

Tags: java, client-server

I have problem with my client-server. When i run server, after client, server write that client is connected with server but i can write nothing in console. Anyone can check where is problem? Because i'm new in java. I try also Scanner but it doesn't work too.

server:

```
package ts_server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.net.ServerSocket;  
import java.net.Socket;  

public class Server  
{  
    private static final int PORT = 50000;  
    static boolean flaga = true;  

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;  
    private static Socket clientSocket;  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
    {  
        serverSocket = null;  
        try  
        {  
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);  
        }  
        catch(IOException e)  
        {  
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: "+PORT);  
            System.exit(1);  
        }  

        System.out.print("Waiting for connection...");  

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()  
        {  
            public void run()  
            {  
                try  
                {  
                    while(flaga)  
                    {  
                        System.out.print(".");  
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  
                    }  
                }  
                catch(InterruptedException ie)  
                {  
                    //  
                }  

                System.out.println("\nClient connected on port "+PORT);  
            }  
        });  
        t.start();  

        clientSocket = null;  
        try  
        {  
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  
            flaga = false;  
        }  
        catch(IOException e)  
        {  
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");  
            t.interrupt();  
            System.exit(1);  
        }  

        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);  
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));  

        t = new Thread(new Runnable()  
        {  
            public void run()  
            {  
                try  
                {  
                    Thread.sleep(5000);  

                    while(true)  
                    {  
                        out.println("Ping");  
                        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Ping sent");  

                        String input = in.readLine();  

                        if(input.equals("Pong"))  
                        {  
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Pong received");  
                        }  
                        else  
                        {  
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Wrong answer");  

                            out.close();  
                            in.close();  
                            clientSocket.close();  
                            serverSocket.close();  
                            break;  
                        }  


                        Thread.sleep(5000);  
                    }  
                }  
                catch(Exception e)  
                {  
                    System.err.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Unexpected Error");  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        t.start();  
    }  
}
```

client:

```
package ts_client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client
{
    private static final int PORT = 50000;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Socket socket = null;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not connect to "+HOST+":"+PORT);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String input = in.readLine();

                        if (input != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Server: " + input);
                        }

                        if (input.equals("Ping"))
                        {
                            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-start>30000)
                            {
                                out.println("Pon g");
                                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Client: Pon g");
                                break;
                            }

                            out.println("Pong");
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Client: Pong");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you expect this code to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: You are ignoring many exceptions -- don't do that. It's kind of like riding a motorcycle with blinders on -- not a very safe thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** close the streams and socket until Client is running.

```
out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: use `volatile` for `static boolean flaga = true;` that is accessed in multi threading.

Comment: Not at all. You are most Welcome

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks a lot. My target is achieved for the day. Time to sleep. Good night.